# How to put an additional summary row on the top of the grid rows with ASPxGridView (Devexpress)?

Tags: asp.net, devexpress, aspxgridview

### The default behavour

When I configure total summaries, with the `<TotalSummary>` node of my `ASPxGridView`, those totals are display at the bottom of the grid.

### My goal

My question is how to make them appear *both* on **the top** and **the bottom** of the grid ?
The position of the top total row would be between the header (column captions / filter) and the first data row.

I'm using the 2011v1 release of ASPxGridView and editors product.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand your question clearly,

For the bottom, you can do it normally with [`totalsummary`](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#AspNet/DevExpressWebASPxGridViewASPxGridView_TotalSummarytopic),

For the top, you can do it like this;

```
protected void ASPxLabel1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            ASPxGridView grid = ASPxGridView1;
            GridViewDataColumn col = grid.Columns["UnitsInStock"] as GridViewDataColumn;
            ASPxSummaryItem summary = grid.TotalSummary["UnitsInStock",
DevExpress.Data.SummaryItemType.Sum];
            string text = summary.GetTotalFooterDisplayText(col, grid.GetTotalSummaryValue(summary));
            ASPxLabel label = (ASPxLabel)sender;
            label.Text = string.Format("{0}\r\n({1})", col.FieldName, text);

        }
```

It gives you a result like this;

[image]

View this [`How to display a total summary within the column header`](http://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/e/E1320.aspx)

Comment: +1 for providing a valid workaround. I'll accept this if i got no other response in few days, but I would really like to see a real "bar" of total item on the top.

Comment: By you say bar, you mean a new row on the header? I don't clearly understand this part.

Comment: Yes, I meant "row" when I said "bar"

Comment: Hmm, I found some article which maybe (I hope) can help you [1](http://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/p/S32819.aspx?searchtext=TotalSummary+top), [2](http://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/e/E2935.aspx?searchtext=TotalSummary+row), [3](http://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/e/E2935.aspx?searchtext=TotalSummary+row), [4](http://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/p/Q324303.aspx?searchtext=TotalSummary+new+row), [5](http://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/p/Q271805.aspx?searchtext=TotalSummary+new+row)

Comment: [6](http://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/p/Q335776.aspx?searchtext=TotalSummary+new+row), [7](http://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/p/Q334893.aspx?searchtext=TotalSummary+new+row). As a final solution, you can ask it in [Devexpress Support](http://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/)